# Algorithm To Disjointly Divide a Graph

Tags: graph-theory, clustering

I had crawled a million page from en.wiktionary.org and each word in a page become vertex and its hyperlinked relation become directed edges.

I'd like to split this directed non-weighted graph disjointly so that I could make search process faster on this graph.

What kind of algorithms and criterias have been researched upon graph dissection?

I don't know name that the academia use to call this dissecting algorithm and relevant research field.

Please let me know if you know any clues.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed as too broad. There is lots written about large graphs like the internet and social networks. Search for social network graph, internet graph, follow links to explanations and academic papers.

Comment: It would be easier if you could give some context, e.g., what you are trying searching for (or why do you even need a graph). BTW, why do you *crawl* their servers, when you can just [download it](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Help:FAQ#Downloading_Wiktionary)?